C# ASP.NET Core : support both appsettings.json and app.config
I have a shared the library that needs some input from the config file, let's say a database helper class with IConfiguration injected in the constructor.
I have an ASP.NET Core app that uses appsettings.json with database connection string. And there is also a .NET Core console app that uses app.config to provide a database connection string. Both of them use the helper class.
However IConfigration only supports appsettings.json format eg. configuration.GetConnectionString. Is there a way to be able to read from both app.config and appsettings.json in uniform code?

"However IConfigration only supports appsettings.json format" No, it supports reading ini, json and xml files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#file-configuration-provider

How about you just simply ask for the connection string as a parameter in your database helper library? That way, the console app can read it from app.config and provide it, while the ASP.NET Core app can read from appsettings.json and provide the connection string from there.

"configuration.GetConnectionString" actually support app.config. But it depends on how you write the config file.
package
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.XML
app.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <ConnectionStrings>
        <DefaultConnection>Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;</DefaultConnection>
    </ConnectionStrings>
</configuration>

    public class DbHelper
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public DbHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
        public string GetConString()
        {
            return configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }
    }

Console App (app.config in debug folder)
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddXmlFile("app.config", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
var helper = new DbHelper(configuration);
var conString = helper.GetConString();

Test result

